# Deploy C++ Executable File, without library dll file

Tags: c++

I created a program and I want to run it on another PC. My program uses libzip.dll. therefore i have to keep this **dll file** with my **exe file** everywhere. How can I make the **dll** independent so I ship only **exe file** to other computers and it shouldn't give error of missing `libzip.dll` file.

Currently I am compiling like this

```
g++ -I C:\MyProject\libzip myprogram.cpp -L. -lzip -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

as `-lzip` seems to be dynamic library I think that's why I must keep it with **exe**. I tried to add like `-static-lzip` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You probably have to compile libzip yourself with the compiler you are using. Edit: if you are using msys2 for your mingw it appears that they have a package containing static libraries since 2018: [https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/pull/3572](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/pull/3572)

Comment: See here on how to install msys2: [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/) and here is the package you need to install if you are using 64 bit code: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-libzip?repo=mingw64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-libzip?repo=mingw64)

Comment: i have MSYS2 in my computer, its a command line. but what to write there? i am sorry  i am totally noob in this.  can you guide me in steps, what to write in msys console ?

Comment: The instruction is in the listing for the package: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libzip` will install the 64 bit libzip package which includes the static library `/mingw64/lib/libzip.a`  you can see that in the file listing for the package.

Comment: Thanks for assistance, btw i am using mingw-w64 i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0 .. i want to run my app on both 32 and 64bit.

Comment: Then you probably want this package: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-i686-libzip?repo=mingw32](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-i686-libzip?repo=mingw32)

Comment: I am using g++ compiler from mingw-w64, i am not using msys but its installed and i also downloaded the package, but still i am getting same error on my compiler g++ .. any idea please.

Comment: Be sure you have `libzip.a` in your package. Then use `g++ -static myprogram.cpp  -lzip` . Notice "-static" will use only static libs (.a), and link all libs to the executable.

Comment: no i dont have libzip.a file in my libzip folder.

Comment: Step 1: Stop using the version of MinGW you're using right now. Might be a good idea to uninstall it, to make sure it doesn't get in the way. Step 2: Follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2) to properly set up MSYS2. Step 3: Use the command Ripi2 told you. It should work then.